Are the triangles AEB and CED congruent?
I have this picture:

The blue line is the segment $AD$ and the dashed blue line is the perpendicular bisector of $AD$. The green line is the bisector of the angle $\angle aOb$
I am quite convinced that $\triangle AEB$ and $\triangle CED$ are congruent, but I was not able to prove it. I did prove that $AE$ and $DE$ are congruent, so now it would be enough to prove that $\angle BAE$ and $\angle CDE$ are.

I think you should give more details about what is given. For example, I don't know what the dashed blue line is supposed to be.

It seems like you made a typo. The two angles are clearly not the same by eyes.

@JohnFrank yeah, I edited the post.

Also, how are AE and DE congruent? If A=C=O, the two lines are clearly not. It seems like it was a mistake or there are details missing in the problem.

@JohnFrank what does A=C=O mean?

If only AB=CD is known, the statement is wrong. What about the blue line? and its normal the dashed blue line? How did you prove AE=DE?

@Elvis The graph didn't give a unique location of A and C

@Elvis If the blue line contains no information, the statement is clearly wrong.

@JohnFrank I have edited the post

If $H$ and $K$ are the projections of point $E$ on lines $a$ and $b$, then $EH=EK$ and from that $DEH=AEK$ (RHS), whence $\angle EDC=\angle EAB$.

@Intelligentipauca I don't see how $DEH=AEK$

They are right triangles having congruent the hypotenuse and a leg (RHS criterion)

The circle around $E$ through $A$ (and $D$) intersects rays $OA$ and $OD$ in $B'$ and $C'$, respectively. Via the reflection at $OE$, we see that $AEB'$ and $DEC'$ are congruent isosceles triangles. From this, your desired equality of $\angle BAE$ and  $\angle CDE$.
